# wait and signal in function

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I have a function which it is a resources (CPU and time) consuming, I need it to run always (while true) but I want an option to wait\ halt (but only that the function will wait and not the thread).
I have tried to create a task that runs a thread soi will be able to wait for the task to finish while being set and reset on the thread.
the code is below.
it doesn't work since the task ends without waiting for the thread to be set\reset.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;



namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task> waitingTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Task>();
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ManualResetEvent> manualResetEvents = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ManualResetEvent>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer;
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            whileTrue(1);

        }

        private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (false)// some condition
            {
                releasePerPrefix(1);
            }
        }

        private void whileTrue(int index)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (true)// some condition  
                {
                    Task waiting = getWaitingTask(index);
                    Console.WriteLine("start waiting " + DateTime.Now);
                    waiting.Wait();
                    ///HERE IS THE PROBLEAM - the waiting task continue imedialty without it being halt\wait\pause
                    Console.WriteLine("Released "+DateTime.Now);
                }
                doJob();
            }
        }

        private void doJob()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("doJob " + DateTime.Now);

        }

        private Task getWaitingTask(int prefix)
        {
            if (!waitingTasks.TryGetValue(prefix, out Task task) || task.IsCompleted)
            {
                task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => waitPerPrefix(prefix)));
                    thread.Start();
                    thread.Join();
                });
                waitingTasks.TryAdd(prefix, task);
            }
            return task;
        }

        private static void waitPerPrefix(int prefix)
        {
            if (!manualResetEvents.TryGetValue(prefix, out ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent))
            {
                manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                manualResetEvents.TryAdd(prefix, manualResetEvent);
            }
            manualResetEvent.Reset();
        }

        private static void releasePerPrefix(int prefix)
        {
            if (!manualResetEvents.TryGetValue(prefix, out ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent))
            {
                manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true);
                manualResetEvents.TryAdd(prefix, manualResetEvent);
            }
            manualResetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty convoluted and I am somewhat confused, too. Please make a step back and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: the whileTrue function is a consumer function that needs to run and get work from the producer using BlockingCollection. I want the whileTrue function to halt and wait and not to consume more until it gets set from another function on the same object.

Comment: In other words: "pause consumption". Then why all those threads and ResetEvents? I'd say all you need is a loop over blockingCollection.Take() on a (one!) thread (or Task). Then pause by waiting on one (class-field) ManualResetEvent ... That should already do the trick?

Comment: Re, "but only that the function will wait and not the thread" Not sure what that means. We often speak of functions doing things, but really, functions never _do_ anything. A function is just a static list of instructions--a recipe. Your recipe for lobster newburg doesn't make itself: Somebody has to _execute_ the recipe if you want to eat. The thing that executes a function is called a _thread_. Threads are the only things in your program that ever do anything, and threads are the only things in your program that can wait.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts :-)
a wait on a (class-field) ManualResetEvent will cause the running thread to wait (no ? )
I want to pause only this consumption function

Comment: Aside: You should not call `TryAdd` and then ignore the result. If it fails you are then left in the dark. If failure is not an expected outcome, just use `Add`.

Comment: Why are you starting a task that starts a thread? This is a very odd thing to do. The Task will run on a thread, starting another thread is wasteful at best. Also use `Task.Run` not `Task.Factory.StartNew` and basiclly let the Task manage the Thread, don't touch the Thread class at all

Comment: Also your blocking `waiting.Wait();` on an async operation. This could cause deadlocks. This code is basically all over the place. I'd spend some time learning about `async`/`await` there is simple too much to try and fix in this question

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.
I will ask it differently - I have implemented a producer-consumer mechanism, using BlockingCollectin.
The producer produce work and the consumer consume it as long there is work in the BlockingCollection. 
The consumer passes the work to workers, each work takes time so I want to halt the consumer from consuming work (which will halt the producer also) to have a better load balance at the works.
The consumer - the consume function is a while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested || !BlockingCollection.IsCompleted) loop -

Comment: I want to halt this function run (and not the thread that run it) when the works are too loaded and signal it to return to consume when the works are less loaded. Hope this explains what I want better.